# How can I put label on top of matInput like bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I'm translating a bootstrap form to a material one. In the following photo I want the mat-form-field to look like the second bootstrap input
[image: form]

But I can't get the label on top of matInput

I've tried this to use the for attribute in label tag:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="paysAdresse">Pays : </label>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Pays :</mat-label>
                    <input matInput id="paysAdresse"  formControlName="pays" placeholder="pays">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="voieAdresse">Voie : </label>
                <input id="voieAdresse" formControlName="voie" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" >
            </div>
```

but it gives me the label and the input in the same line. 
how can I achieve the wanted result ?

Comment: Your best bet would be to create a custom input element with content projection using material for styling only the <input> element.

Comment: Let me know whether my solution solves your issues

Comment: @BogdanB Why to use content projection I am sure it would be a bad choice, I would Stick to `KISS`. it can be easily achieved using CSS

Comment: @Aminos did my answer help?

Answer (score 5):

it can be easily achieved using Flex layout:
Use
`flex-direction: column:The flexible items are displayed vertically, as a column`
Add this to your component CSS file

```
.form-group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Modified Html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="paysAdresse">Pays : </label>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput id="paysAdresse" formControlName="pays" placeholder="pays">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**[`liveDemo`](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkkgldbelknb?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.ts)**